# Eloquent ORM - name for column on condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using Eloquent and I have Event model. It has created_at field. I am trying to select some events and for each to set a property `type` with value based on the column `created_at`. For example if `created_at` < today the event is already passed and the `type` property is 'passed'. Is there a way to do this through the query builder `Event::select('if created_at < NOW()`passes`else if .... as type');`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. You can use either eloquent scopes or mutators.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes -> check for Local Scopes
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators -> check for Accessors & Mutators

I'm guessing you're using the latest Laravel LTM version.

The local scope solution will allow you to do `Event::passed()->etc()` and the Accessors append a flag to the Event object saying `passed => true`.